# About active and static modes in processing

Tags: java, processing

How to use active and static modes at the same time?

Like if I am drawing an ellipse and a rectangle, I only want to make ellipse static, not the rectangle.

Comment: What is "satic" mode? I'm not familiar with this term -- is it Processing-specific?

Answer (score 1):

There are generally two approaches to this:

**Approach One:** Just redraw everything every frame. Draw a background to clear out old frames, then draw the ellipse, and then draw the rectangle.

**Approach Two:** Draw the ellipse once to a buffer. The `createGraphics()` function is your friend here. Then in the `draw()` function, draw the buffer to the screen, then draw the rectangle.

Generally you should go with approach one, unless the static part of your sketch is complicated, then you should go with the second approach.